# How do I call an unreferenced method from a distant class? (C# and VB.NET allowed)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, oop

For the life of me I can't find a solution for this:
I have a class set up that does several things, one of which is manipulate [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) windows. One of these windows is the `MainWindow.xaml`.

So for instance I want this class to close the `MainWindow.xaml`, that is if for example a method is called from within `OtherClass.cs`.

**Basically: I want to access unreferenced methods in the codebehind of a window (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`) from a distant class, though within the same project (Visual Studio).**

---

When I use the MainWindow (`using MainWindow` or `imports MainWindow` in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)) and use its members for closing the window, as so:

```
using MainWindow
Public class OtherClass
{
    // OtherClass is instanced elsewhere and then is decided to close MainWindow.
    // So I imagine doing the following:
    private void CommandClose()
    {
        CloseMainWindow();
    }
    ...
}
```

And inside MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
Public class MainWindow
{
    Public void CloseMainWindow()
    {
        this.close();
    }
    ...
}
```

Though I receive the following error: *"Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference".*

Meaning I should do something like:

```
using MainWindow
Public class OtherClass
{
    MainWindow myWindow // Though now I have a new window :/
    private void CommandClose()
    {
       myWindow.CloseMainWindow();
    }
    ...
}
```

So to access any members within MainWindow.xaml.cs and not create a new instance I need them to be shared? But that would defeat the purpose of having it do anything to the window, because the close command wouldn't be available then!

I might be overlooking some things, but atm I can't seem to notice it.
Would anyone be so kind as to show me a way to handle such a situation?

NB I am working in Windows Presentation Foundation if anyone was wondering.

---

To clarify further, here is a comment to one of the previous answers describing my situation:

> What I am trying to do is run a command within another class, which is a public member of a WPF window. The window is already instanced and displayed. I just want to access its public members so I can manipulate the window from another class for convenience sake. This OtherClass.cs of mine is a class that handles console actions. The console is a custom control situated in the MainWindow.xaml.cs. When the user types for instance: /close, I want the MainWindow.xaml to close, but not just that, for in the future I want to add more features.

Comment: So, as good OOP, I would move these commands out of MainWindow, since they don't seem to be about only MainWindow.

Comment: They are actually: MainWindow is currently the only window that requires these manipulations. Though if you suggest I could improve on something - I would gladly hear it.

Comment: I think I would have `OtherClass` do the parsing, and I would also have it expose a set of public events - one for each command. I would  have `MainWindow` subscribe to the `CloseWindows` event from `OtherClass`.

Comment: Quite brilliant - I have implemented it that way; thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need an object reference. And you're gonna have to use the application context for that.

Here's how you would get a list of references to whatever type of window you have open and also close them:

```
    var windows = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>();
    foreach (var window in windows)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
```

You could call any other method you want on them, and you can search for any other type of window, but this is how you find the one you're specifically looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought that Application.Current exposed all the windows. Are there alternatives to this, though?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to invoke a method like that across classes. You could make a static window closing method and have a list of the active windows within the class, and when the method is called, it closes all windows in the list. That way you wouldn't need an object reference, at least in the method you are calling from.